# How to obtain the metric(s) from an action?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

So I am confused about dimensional reduction. Because most litterature that I have found so far jump over the steps where they obtain the corresponding metric(s) from some action.

In particular, I have been looking at section 2 in [this paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/JHEP12(2014)066) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266319647_Dimensional_reduction_of_BPS_attractors_in_AdS_gauged_supergravities)).

But my question is general. In GR classes, I remember that I have worked a lot with the AdS metric, but I have never actually seen where these metrics come from starting from the field equations.

Understanding this proceedure would help me understand how they get equation (2.3) in the above paper, because I really don't see what is going on.

So, is there a general procedure on how I can get corresponding metrics for the EH actio? In particular the vacuum solution?

Comment: General relativity gets its solutions in quite generally the same way as any other physical theory : solve your Einstein field equations given some initial conditions (in the case of GR, the initial conditions are the values of the metric and its derivatives at some initial time). The process is a lot more complicated than for most theories but otherwise the general idea remains the same.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a good reference that would spell out some of these details explicitly?